# Find out how wide a set of children is

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a WP theme, and am having some trouble with the navigation.

The basic markup looks like this:

```
#navbar
    ul.main-nav
        li.menu-item.drop-submenu
            ul.submenu
                li.menu-item.drop-submenu
                    ul.submenu
                        li.menu-item.drop-submenu
                           etc. (any menu item can have unlimited submenus)
        li.menu-item.drop-submenu
            ul.submenu
                li.menu-item
                li.menu-item
        li.menu-item
```

Now the problem I'm having is that a menu item with 2 or more submenus spanning to the right will eventually overflow off viewport. I'm using jquery to calculate the width and offset of the submenus and apply a class that will cause the submenus to drop on the left instead should they cause overflow. This was relatively easy to do for the "top-level" submenus, but i'm drawing a blank for the nested submenus.

Basically, i'm looking for a way to find out what set of submenus spans most to the right, but not the collective width of all nested subs, if that makes any sense...

I'm not even sure how to explain this properly, so if something is unclear i will try my best to clarify. Thank you in advance, any push in the right direction will be much appreciated.

EDIT: Made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61pj9jhb/1/)

Comment: I think you're doing a fine job explaining... Yet, nothing explains better than a codepen or fiddle. can you slap one of those together? happy to help.

Comment: Done, added in the edit :)

Comment: Did you forget ur jquery?

Comment: Sorry, didn't think it would help, but i added it in and edited the fiddle further. The second menu item is pulled to the left and its submenus will drop to the left, that part of the script works. However, hovering over the third submenu in item 1 you will see the issue. The multi-level function is unfinished because i was thinking about how to solve this problem and just got stuck.

Comment: check my edit; not the prettiest, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, i'm looking for a way to find out what set of submenus
> spans most to the right, but not the collective width of all nested
> subs, if that makes any sense...

So, this will select all of the innermost submenus, which in your case would*(right?)* be those furthest to the right.

```
var $rightmost = $(".main-nav").find('.submenu:not(:has(.submenu))');
```

You could repeatedly select elements in the following way, adding a `.left` class to all outlying `.submenu`s until **all** pass the in-viewport check you're running. Maybe put it in a while loop and see if your query results have a length, then run your checking and handling logic within.

```
var $rightmost = $(".main-nav").find('.submenu:not(:has(.submenu)):not(.left)');
```

lol. it's late here and i'm delirious, so if this sucks or doesn't make a clear argument, speak up!
**Admittedly:** I did not check this, so also speak up if it's funky.

### Assumption

because of this,

> I'm using jquery to calculate the width and offset of the submenus and
> apply a class that will cause the submenus to drop on the left instead
> should they cause overflow.

I'm operating under the assumption that you've already coded the viewport logic.

## Edit: [this works](http://jsfiddle.net/61pj9jhb/33/)

though it could be optimized... And I didn't at all do it in the *I think* cool way I proposed. **GSD**

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's definitely a step in the right direction. Instead of traversing downwards, i should have traversed upwards from the last submenu like you suggested. Do i feel stupid lol. However, this is not ideal since the first level will drop to the right and if the next one overflows, it will drop to the left thus overlapping the parent. I'll tinker some more and try to figure it out. Still, your answer helped a lot so i'll mark it as the accepted answer and post my final solution here once i figure it out.

Comment: P.S. Go to sleep dude, i had the habit to stay up ridiculously late too but soon realized i can't do much work when i'm deliriously tired :)

Comment: Oh, I guess I was just thinking along the lines of text wrap. in that case, just select all of the innermost submenus, see if they overlap; if so, add `.left` class to all parent submenus.

Comment: You could do that like `$(this).parents('.submenu').addBack().addClass("left");`

Comment: Lol. Passion projects all night and rando StackO muckery, and ooops... I have a real job now. Glad I could help, man. cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at the [Jquery positionCalculator](http://tlindig.github.io/position-calculator/) that allows your script to check for collisions automatically (See the Bootstrap dropdown example at the bottom of the page).

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful script and will definitely come in handy later, but isn't right for my current issue, mainly because the submenus are absolutely positioned behind their parent items until hovered, thus it will not detect any collisions.